# Print balance in CSV using Ledger cli

Tags: csv, command-line-interface, export-to-csv

Ledger (http://ledger-cli.org/) allows to output reverse sorted balance of your Income accounts using the following command:

```
ledger -f money.txt bal Income --sort "-abs(total)"
```

so the output looks like follows:

```
  $-7,715.00  Income
  $-6,789.10    Payroll
    $-567.89    Insurance
    $-234.56    Gift Card
    $-200.56      Store 1  
     $-34.00      Store 2
    $-123.45    Coupons
```

Is there a way to output the same information in CSV format, but keeping the indentation of the categories as follows (header values are not important)?

```
    "Amount","Level 1","Level 2,"Level 3"
    $-7,715.00,Income,,
    ,$-6,789.10,Payroll,
    ,$-567.89,Insurance,
    ,$-234.56,Gift Card,
    ,,$-200.56,Store 1
    ,,$-34.00,Store 2
    ,$-123.45,Coupons,
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--balance-format` option with any of the [documented format strings](https://www.ledger-cli.org/3.0/doc/ledger3.html#Format-Strings).

For example to print the account name and total amount on each line:

`ledger -f money.txt balance ^Income --no-total --balance-format '%A,%T\n'`

Comment: This does not work out well if a single account has a balance with more than one commodity.  Once of the commodity totals will end up on a line by itself.